# Cosine expression in C

Tags: c, expression

How can I write 3 cos² 2x with C?

Comment: Do you mean by using library functions, or by implementing a convergent series summation? Or are you asking about basic C syntax?

Comment: Post what you have tried/

Comment: using <math.h> only

Comment: FWIW: 2*cos²(th) = 1 + cos(2*th).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming x is in radians :

```
3*pow(cos(2*x),2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function for your purpose:

```
#include <math.h>

double f(double x) {
    double c = cos(2 * x);
    return c * c * 3;
}
```

First compute *cos 2x*, then square the result and multiply by 3.